# Default Button Format on activity_main.xml Causing Crash

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio, and I'm following [this](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/5914-android-adventures-activity-and-ui.html?start=2) tutorial to learn how to code. I put a button into my activity_main.xml and referenced the *onClick* property of the button to the method *buttonOnClick* in my MainActivity.java file using the drag-and-drop method (Design tab of the xml file). The original code is as follows:

activity_main.xml (non-relevant code omitted):

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick (MainActivity)" />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button) v;
    button.setText("Click");
  }
```

After I ran this code, when I clicked the button, it crashed. If I removed the *(MainActivity)* part of the *onClick* property, it worked. I have no idea why this worked, but it did. Would someone perhaps be able to tell me why?

The error message I received when the app crashed is as follows:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method buttonOnClick
>   (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
>   android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that (View) is assumed so you do not need to ask for (MainActivity) as well.

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick" />
```

Comment: Hmmm... Given my method was `buttonOnClick(View)` and the xml was looking for `buttonOnClick(MainActivity)(View)` (according to the error message), I suppose that makes sense. In what instance would it be necessary to ask for (MainActivity)?

Comment: If you were to ask for that, then where would the button look to find an instance of MainActivity to give you? It is already coded and would not know how to handle an extra output. This is likely why it displayed it as buttonOnClick(View) instead of buttonOnClick(MainActivity, View)

Comment: Alright then. I guess that makes sense. Thanks for giving me a probably obvious answer to my question. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `android:onClick="buttonOnClick (MainActivity)"` to

```
 android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
remove  android:onClick="buttonOnClick (MainActivity)" from xml

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

write the onClick in code

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button b1; 

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);  
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){  

            @Override  
            public void onClick(View view) { 
            b1.setText("Click");


  }

     }); 

    }

    }
```